# Cant Multiply Sequence By Non-Int By Type 'Str'

Tags: python-2.7

```
print "This is to find the area of a rectangle "
print "What is the length of your rectangle?"
x = raw_input("The length of the rectangle is ") 
print "What is the width of your rectangle?"
y= raw_input("The width of the rectangle is ")
z = x * y
print z
```

Answer (score 1):

[raw_input()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input) returns a string. Python doesn't know how to multiply strings and throws a `TypeError`:

```
>>> x = raw_input("The length of the rectangle is ")
The length of the rectangle is 10
>>> type(x)
<type 'str'>
>>> y= raw_input("The width of the rectangle is ")
The width of the rectangle is 20
>>> type(y)
<type 'str'>
>>> x * y
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'str'
```

You need to cast inputs to `int`:

```
x = int(raw_input("The length of the rectangle is "))
```

Demo:

```
>>> x = int(raw_input("The length of the rectangle is "))
The length of the rectangle is 10
>>> y= int(raw_input("The width of the rectangle is "))
The width of the rectangle is 20
>>> z = x * y
>>> print z
200
```

Answer (score 1):

Very simply, you cannot multiply by strings. This is because even if you input a number, `raw_input` stores all input as string. Just cast it as an `int` to fix your problem:

```
print "This is to find the area of a rectangle "
print "What is the length of your rectangle?"
x = int(raw_input("The length of the rectangle is "))
print "What is the width of your rectangle?"
y= int(raw_input("The width of the rectangle is "))
z = x * y
print z
```

#### python's raw_input

```
>>> a = raw_input('Enter value: ')
Enter value: 5
>>> type(a)
<type 'str'>
>>> b = int(raw_input('Enter value: '))
Enter value: 5
>>> type(b)
<type 'int'>
```

### [NOTE]

You can also reduce the amount of printing by just doing this: (It also makes your code easier to understand)

```
x = int(raw_input("What is the length of your rectangle?: "))
y= int(raw_input("What is the width of your rectangle?: "))
z = x * y
print z
```